# how to hide rightCalloutAccessoryView for some annotation "disclosure button"

Tags: ios, ios5, mkannotationview

i have only one class for the annotation ..

for one reason, the annotation show only the title, and it have different pinColor  and i did that very well by declaring a method in annotation class ..

but i want to hide the disclosure button for the same reason ..

i only know that the rightCalloutAccessoryView can be declared with viewForAnnotation method in my mapview class

So what can i do?
how to change the view for the callout by hiding the disclosure button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

back, i solved it!

i write an if statement .. to check the title for the annotation ..

based on this solution ..[here is it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066362/mkmapview-display-a-button-for-my-location)